# elementwise vs global repetition in R

Tags: r, repeat

I'd like to create a vector by repeating the elements of an other one n times in R.

o <- (1, 2, 3)
n = 3

I'd like to see
result_a (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
result_b (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)

Thanks,
Zs

Comment: Look at `?rep`.  That does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example using the `rep` command:

```
> o <- c(1,2,3)
> n <- 3
> rep(o, each=3)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
> rep(o,3)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```